# Stack Apps display issue

Tags: bug, design, stackapps

I wanted to report a small display bug on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/tour).

The user name text is cropped on the main view, and in the printscreen you can see that the last letter of each user is cut. (Like *Bhargav Rao* is seen as *Bhargav Rac*.)

I can reproduce the bug on Edge, Internet Explorer, and Chrome. I run on Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Bhargav Rac, let me laugh for now.